# What are "optional" Maven dependencies?

Tags: maven

I've always wondered what these are. I've read the Maven documentation about this and I don't think I really understand it. Could somebody please explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Optional dependencies are used when it's not really possible (for whatever reason) to split a project up into sub-modules. The idea is that some of the dependencies are only used for certain features in the project, and will not be needed if that feature isn't used. Ideally, such a feature would be split into a sub-module that depended on the core functionality project...this new subproject would have only non-optional dependencies, since you'd need them all if you decided to use the subproject's functionality.
>
> However, since the project cannot be split up (again, for whatever reason), these dependencies are declared optional. If a user wants to use functionality related to an optional dependency, they will have to redeclare that optional dependency in their own project. This is not the most clear way to handle this situation, but then again both optional dependencies and dependency exclusions are stop-gap solutions.

Reference: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html